# how to merge javascript objects in MS Edge

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

In Chrome, Firefox & Safari I can merge 2 javascript objects using the spread operator:

```
const obj = { ...{'een' : 1}, ...{'twee': 2}}
```

but in MS Edge I get:

```
Expected identifier, string or number
```

...Why? !MS

Comment: Upgrade to Edge Chromium

Comment: it seems that it doesn't support it although that's odd, which version are you running?

Comment: Maybe try lodash's merge() for browsers? https://github.com/lodash/lodash

Comment: @EugenSunic & rest: I'm on Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1098.0. Company installation, so not in the position to update or do anything else. Copyrigh from 2018. Currently I feel most effective thing to do is tell my audience to avoid MS browsers.

Comment: The suggestion given by @Gbr22 can help to solve your issue. Object.assign is working fine with the MS Edge legacy browser. I suggest you can try to test it in the MS Edge legacy browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
const objects = [{'een' : 1},{'twee': 2}];
let obj = {};
objects.forEach(e=>Object.assign(obj,e));
console.log(obj);
```